# Problem while running mysql

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, mysql, phpmyadmin

The term and the code of mine is here below:

```
root@fair-VirtualBox:/home/fair# sudo systemctl status mysql
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Welcome! What is the output of the command `sudo journalctl -u mysql.service`? [edit] the post, don't add it in the comments, and format it with the code tool `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

The service is listed as disabled.

Have you tried running:

```
 sudo systemctl start mysql
 sudo systemctl enable mysql
```

To start and enable the process?

It's weird that it would be disabled as it is enabled and started by default on most Ubuntu installations (and you can see in your output: `vendor preset: enabled`). BTW which Ubuntu version are you running? If this does not fix the problem, please list the output of `systemctl status mysql` and `sudo journalctl -u mysql.service` as suggested already, after running the above commands.

Answer (score 0):

yes I try the above mention commands also, but it not get working...

command which I try is here below: 
sudo systemctl start mysql
sudo systemctl enable mysql

and my running output while try to run the commands is here below:

fair@fair-VirtualBox:~$ sudo systemctl start mysql
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
fair@fair-VirtualBox:~$  sudo systemctl enable mysql
Synchronizing state of mysql.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mysql

Comment: So did you try `systemctl status mysql.service` or `journalctl -xe` as the error messages suggest? It will tell you the reason why it failed, and without it we can't really help.